# Is there a difference between "Nothing exists in the universe" and "Nothing exists, not even the universe"?

Tags: existence

Is there a difference between claiming "Nothing exists in the universe" and claiming "Nothing exists, not even the universe"? It seems to me that the former implies the universe, at least, exists, even if nothing else does. Of course, both statements are false, but I am wondering if there is a distinction between them.

Comment: Maybe... the first one seems to be about en empty universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these statements are different in meaning. The first one indicates that there are one or two things -- This empty universe and I.  Sometimes the speaker may be implying that there is not even I...the empty universe is the eternal truth.

The second only indicates complete emptiness.

If emptiness is given importance there is no need to mention the word, 'universe'.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/universe

Both these statements don't give importance even to the speaker or his existence.